# How to select the entire row, while having only first(one) column clickable?

Tags: javascript, r, datatable, dt

I need to do the same as here:

https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple.html

Ideally with a checkbox.

With the select extension, this is configured simply: `select = list(style = 'multi+shift', selector = "td:first-child"),`

Only via the built-in `selectable` that works with the server-side on the R...

How to do it?